# Power Off button is gone on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: shutdown, gnome-shell, indicator, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop and I noticed that I no longer have the Power Off button but rather a menu that I need to click on and then I need to click on Power Off... and then Power Off. Is there a way to get the button back?

Comment: you want the exact button like in previous versions or get rid of that submenu is 0k??

Comment: Any button would do but getting rid of the sub menus is fine too

Comment: Jesus Christ, who in their right mind would think this was I good idea? :(((

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use this extension which brings out the submenu and rearrange the order.

[Bring Out Sub Menu Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/)

[image]

If you need installation Instructions..

1. Download the Extension from the above link like this.
   [image]
2. Go to the downloaded location/Directory/path.
3. Right-click in the empty place and click "Open in Terminal"
4. run the command

   ```
   gnome-extensions install BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButtonpratap.fastmail.fm.v5.shell-extension.zip
   ```

   (Note that tab completion is available, you dont need to type entire file name, Just type "BringOut" and hit tab)
5. Refresh the gnome-shell with "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `r`" <kbd>Enter</kbd> method.
6. run the command

   ```
   gnome-extensions enable BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButton@pratap.fastmail.fm
   ```
7. Refresh the gnome-shell with "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `r`" <kbd>Enter</kbd> method.

Now you will see the submenu out of it and merged with system menu.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the numerous clicks to get to the Power-off button, you may create a keyboard shortcut linked to `gnome-session-quit --power-off`. It's even quicker than using the menu.

1. Open Settings/Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Go to the end of the list and press the "+" sign
3. Under Name I entered Power off, but more importantly enter the above mentioned command as the one to run.
4. Choose a shortcut of your choice. I chose <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Bring Out Submenu Of Power Off/Logout Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/) by pratap@fastmail.fm via **extension-manager**. Just find the extension and install it within app

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```