# How to customise 20.04 lockscreen?

Tags: desktop-background, 20.04

I've just updated to ubuntu 20.04, and I am not happy with the default lockscreen - it's just a heavily blurred version of my wallpaper with the clock. Is there a way to change how this looks? At the very least, I would like to reduce the blur on the wallpaper so I can actually see it.

Answer (score 5):

you can use  [Control Blur](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2935/control-blur-effect-on-lock-screen/)  Extension to Control the Blur Effect.

Blur Sigma Value set to 0
[image]

Blur Sigma Value set to 4
[image]

Blur Sigma Value set to 100
[image]

you can follow the installation instructions from this  [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232696/739431)

Or you may use this wonderful extension  [Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1476/unlock-dialog-background/)