# Keep Gnome system menu open always

Tags: gnome, system-settings, gnome-panel

Is there a way I can keep open the top right corner "System Menu" options?
Example: In the picture below I opened Power-off/Logout menu, can it be remained open always so that I can save a click every time.

[image]

Comment: related? https://askubuntu.com/q/1232688/739431

Comment: Actually, I was looking for all the menus. Thanks, this extension works at least for power-off/logout.

Comment: all the menus.. you mean wifi.. battery Bluetooth asianet news etc??

Comment: Yes, to keep them all open.