# How to install and run gsconnect

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, kde-connect

I am trying to download gsconnect on my ubuntu 20.04 but the apt download does not show anything in the tray and has no cli command apparently. So I read on a forum the one on the gnome.extensions site works but it's just a zip folder filled with .js files with no instructions I have no idea how to run or install that. No instructions on the site or anywhere on google to be found too besides install gsconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have downloaded the zip folder in your `$HOME/Downloads/` directory.

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
gnome-extensions install gsconnectandyholmes.github.io.v43.shell-extension.zip
```

Refresh gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r enter method.

```
gnome-extensions enable gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
```

Again Refresh gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r enter method.

[image]

Further, go through this post and concentrate on Installation Instructions. https://askubuntu.com/a/1232696/739431

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you download the plugin for your browser as well
Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gsconnect/
Chromium:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gsconnect/jfnifeihccihocjbfcfhicmmgpjicaec

Comment: Can you advise how to do that?