# Move Date from Center to Right on GNOME top bar

Tags: gnome-shell, notification

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

I need to move "notification day and time" to right side corner. Right now it is located at middle of the screen.

I'm unable to install Gnome tweak tool. Can anyone help to move notification other than installing gnome tweak tool idea?

[image]

Comment: The GNOME desktop environment is not really designed to prioritize extensive customization of the UI elements, which is why additional software like "tweaks" are needed to add a few additional customization options.  The GNOME devs prioritize consistency and ease-of-use above user customization.  If you want/need to relocate elements of the UI, you might consider using a different desktop environment like KDE (Kubuntu) or Xfce (Xubuntu).  You can boot these flavors from a live session to test them out without having to install anything.

Comment: The short version of the above comment is "No".

Comment: Have you considered installing Cinnamon?

Comment: This os version is much comfortable for my work. So can't change

Comment: @sivasdpi gnome-tweaks can't help for your requirement. gnome extensions can help in achieving close to your requirement. Are extensions Ok for you?

Comment: Yes pls. Suggest how to do using extensions @unknown

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org search for "dash to dock" and "dash to panel" I think 18.04 gnome-shell version is 3.36 so select this version and down load zip files. Then I will give commands to install extension.

Comment: Once zip files are downloaded.. follow the steps from here.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1232696/739431

Comment: From above link, Commands 4 and 6 needs variables based on your preferred extension. Dash to Panel. Or Dash to Dock.

Comment: are you looking for something like this?? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZxFt.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV8Zg.jpg

Comment: You are correct , @unknown. Like that i need. Can u pls do this all for me via screen sharing ? Will fix time, day to do. Pls give ur email id .

Comment: Hi Just one single line command is required in terminal. Do you want like 1st image or 2nd Image?

Comment: Like 1st screen and 12 hrs clock time format

Comment: The time format will be as per your screen shot. I will write command in Answer. In few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To move to the Right side run the below command.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel._centerBox.remove_child(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container); Main.panel._rightBox.insert_child_at_index(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container, 0);'
```

To make it to normal, run the below command.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel._rightBox.remove_child(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container); Main.panel._centerBox.add_child(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container);'
```

You need to add the first command to startup applications list for persistence. Otherwise after every logout and login, you need to run the first command.

[image]

Comment: do just above two commands sufficient or do I need to install extensions which u had said earlier ?

Comment: No need extensions

Comment: I had attached above error. It's better we can do screen sharing and rectify it. Pls send your email address.

Comment: First command worked. But after logged out again notification came to center. How to add the first command to startup applications list for persistence?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en

Comment: Are chrome notifications some how different? This is definitely not working on 21.10.

Comment: @UnKNOWn which gnome extension and how to activate? Just tried panel osd and no good so far ... can't even find it once installed.

Comment: @UnKNOWn ah got it now ... SUPER unintuitive. You go to this site https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/ and "ON" to install. THEN CRITICALLY YOU NEED TO RELOAD THE SITE! Then you get a settings option there next to the install buttons. There you change things. I don't understand how this works from a site. Seem crazy. Will this work offline?