# How to put notifications back to top righ on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gnome, notification, 21.10

Notifications are abusive in the top middle. It is dangerous as it click harvests in the middle of critical operations.

There are Gnome extensions to do this but everything looks dodgy. What is the CLEAR TRUE PATH to fixing this problem involving the least number of dodgy installs?

This site https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/change-position-of-notifications-on-ubuntu is incomplete and does not offer complete instructions on what is required to install.

UPDATE:

This seemed to work eventually https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/ ... you need to install from the site, then hit reload, then see the settings appear on the page and click that.

Answer (score 2):

Without extensions, I'd say to set up a command on [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) that allows you to move the bar via gdbus and persist after reboot, as suggested in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346312/move-date-from-center-to-right-on-gnome-top-bar):

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel._centerBox.remove_child(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container); Main.panel._rightBox.insert_child_at_index(Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu.container, 0);'
```

Comment: So far this is not working. Any other ideas? I can't belive they changed this.

Comment: @mathtick is the problem related to automating this process using Startup-Applications, or if you paste the command in your terminal it won't do anything at all? The only other solution I can think of is using this extension (https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd ). I never used it though, and don't know if you'd find it "dodgy", so try it at your own risk.

Comment: In the end this worked: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/ ... you need to install from the site, then hit reload, then see the settings appear on the page and click that.